# Add Associated includes on rails based on different source type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a polymorphic table that contains a source type and source id. Source type could be animal or plant. Now both animals and plants have different associations. Based on the source type, I want to easy load with includes its associated data.

```
questions.includes(
  source: [
    :constant_setting,
    :category,
    :user,
    comments: [:user],
    parent: [user: [:employees, :company]],
    children: [user: [:employees, :company]]
  ]
)
```

This could be the association for source: animal. But when one of the sources is the plant, it throws an association not found an error. How do I include source type for both plant and animal

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to eager load associations for all source types. That's because for each record, ActiveRecord will try to fetch all the `included` relations, which, depending on source type, would either exist or not exist for some records.

You could either **not** eager load, if that serves your use case, or you could load the objects separately. Something like the following:

```
questions_for_animals = Question.where(source_type: "Animal").includes(<all relations of animals you want to pre load>)

questions_for_plants = Question.where(source_type: "Plant").includes(<all relations of plants you want to pre load>)
```